# Activating two jQuery functions with one link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do the following:

- Open a div with **slideToggle**
- Move the users window to the top of the div with **scrollTop**
- Then basically reverse the process when the user closes the div.

I have the whole process almost finished, but I am having one problem. When I open the div my window doesn't move to the top of the div. But when I close the div my window does move to where I want it.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
// Find the location of a div (x, y)
function divLoc(object) {
var topCord = 0;

// If browser supports offsetParent
if(object.offsetParent) {
    do {
        topCord += object.offsetHeight;
    } 
    while (object === object.offsetParent);

    return topCord;
}
}

$("#open").click(function () {
    var newInfo = document.getElementById("newInfo");
    var location = divLoc(newInfo);
    $("#newInfo").slideToggle('slow', function() {
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: location }, 2000);
    });
});
```

And I uploaded an example of the problem on jsFiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hWapT/)

Comment: I think your while condition should be (object = object.offsetParent)

Comment: That's suppose to be there. It makes sure to add the height of all surrounding divs.

Comment: When you say "Then basically reverse the process when the user closes the div.", what do you want to happen to `scrollTop`? Return to top of the window? Have it go back to the button position?

Comment: I'm going to add that [return to the top] now since I got the answer to fix my problem.

Comment: @ChrisFrank agreed, but for your while loop to keep adding offsets from each successive parent, you need to update the object to be the previous iteration's offsetParent each time you go through the loop. That's why I think your condition should be (object = object.offsetParent)

Comment: @Andbdrew Or I could initialize the object variable, then reference it in the while statement. I think both solutions are good.

Comment: @ChrisFrank `object === object.offsetParent` will never be true, so your loop will not add up all of the surrounding offsets.

Comment: Now that I look at it, I'm realizing how stupid I was, your right. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need change slide function:

```
$("#newInfo").slideToggle('slow', function() {
  var self = $(this)       
  $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: self.offset().top }, 2000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hSHz5/